# Code to get user input not executing/skipping in C++

Tags: c++, string, input, getline

In the below code, I'm running into an error when I try to get the user to input their name. My program just skips it over and goes right over to making the function calls without allowing the user to enter their name. Despite the error, my program is compiling. I'm not sure what's going wrong as I wrote that part based off other examples I found on here. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

char showMenu();
void getLottoPicks(int[]);
void genWinNums(int[]);
bool noDuplicates(int[]);

const int SIZE = 7;

int main()
{
    int userTicket[SIZE] = {0};
    int winningNums[SIZE] = {0};
    char choice;
    string name;

    srand(time(NULL));

    do
    {
        choice = showMenu();

        if (choice == '1')
        {
            cout << "Please enter your name: " << endl;
            getline(cin, name);

            getLottoPicks(userTicket);
            genWinNums(winningNums);

            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                cout << winningNums[i];
        }
    } while (choice != 'Q' && choice != 'q');

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Added the code for showMenu:

```
char showMenu()
{
    char choice;

    cout << "LITTLETON CITY LOTTO MODEL:" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "1) Play Lotto" << endl;
    cout << "Q) Quit Program" << endl;
    cout << "Please make a selection: " << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    return choice;
}
```

And getLottoPicks (this part is very wrong and I'm still working on it):

```
void getLottoPicks(int numbers[])
{
    cout << "Please enter your 7 lotto number picks between 1 and 40: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << "Selection #" << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> numbers[i];
        if (numbers[i] < 1 || numbers[i] > 40)
        {
            cout << "Please choose a number between 1 and 40: " << endl;
            cin >> numbers[i];
        }
        if (noDuplicates(numbers) == false)
            {
                do
                {
                cout << "You already picked this number. Please enter a different number: " << endl;
                cin >> numbers[i];
                noDuplicates(numbers);
                } while (noDuplicates(numbers) == false);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code for ShowMenu?

Comment: And `getLottoPicks`, etc.

Comment: @enhzflep I edited my question with the code.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I added the code for getLottoPicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing `cin >> choice;` inside `char showMenu()`, if a user inputs `1[ENTER]`, the `char` consumes 1 character from cin, and the newline **stays** inside the stream. Then, when the program gets to `getline(cin, name);`, it notices that there's still something inside `cin`, and reads it. It's a newline character, so `getline` gets it and returns. That's why the program is behaving the way it is.

In order to fix it - add `cin.ignore();` inside `char showMenu()`, right after you read the input. `cin.ignore()` ignores the next character - in our case, the newline char.

And a word of advice - try **not** to mix `getline` with `operator >>`. They work in a slightly different way, and can get you into trouble! Or, at least remember to always `ignore()` after you get anything from `std::cin`. It may save you a lot of work.

This fixes the code:

```
char showMenu()
{
    char choice;

    cout << "LITTLETON CITY LOTTO MODEL:" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "1) Play Lotto" << endl;
    cout << "Q) Quit Program" << endl;
    cout << "Please make a selection: " << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    cin.ignore();

    return choice;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, it works perfectly now. I would have never figured this out on my own given my limited knowledge. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

from looking at code `showMenu` function has problem. and it's not returning asccii equivalent of `'1'` that is: 31 integer. try printing value returned by `showmenu`. you will get that

**UPDATE:**
  It is because `cin` in delimited by `' '`(whitespace) and `getline` by `'\n'` character, so when enter name and press enter `cin` in `showmenu` will consume whole string except `'\n'` from `istream` and that is read by `getline`. to see this when it ask for choice enter string like `1 myname` (1 whitespace myname)and press ENTER will display name. now `cin` will read 1 in `choice` and `myname` in name by `getline`.

Comment: No, showMenu() is correct. It is returning the char '1' and it goes to the next line in the program and prints out "Please enter your name: " but after that it skips right to getLottoPicks() without allowing the user to enter their name.